# AWS Firewall Configuration Review

Tags: audit

We had a situation where an incorrect AWS firewall rule buried in our configuration was causing some headaches.  After a few days we found the rule and fixed it.  Does anyone know of a good way to audit Amazon AWS firewall configurations to better visualize configurations to get in front of these issues before they become a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called AWS Security Group visualization.  It's essentially turning your security groups, their rules, and their relationships into a diagram or set of diagrams.

Commercial solutions like Dome9 and VisualOps IDEprovide visualizations given access to your accounts:
http://www.dome9.com/clarity
https://medium.com/@visualops/visualize-your-aws-vpc-4668790162b3

There are also open source solutions to this:
http://shokunin.co/blog/2013/04/04/ec2secviz.html

YMMV with very complex rule sets.  We have over 80 security groups and the visualizations get tangly fast.